# Whats is the correct element type for this selenium project?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to find something out but nothing works.
I'm trying to use a web scraper, to print all of the hot deal percentages on this website:
' https://shadowpay.com/en?price_from=0.00&price_to=34.00&game=csgo&hot_deal=true '
But I ran into an error (I have tried many ways to go about this, but I think that it's my lack of HTML)
The error is that the element that I want to print ('percent-hot-deal__block'), isn't a class name, but I've tried a lot of find_element_by options, nothing worked, so I'm coming here.
Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
import time
#
perc = []
#
PATH = 'C:/Users/<user__name>/Documents/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://shadowpay.com/en?price_from=0.00&price_to=34.00&game=csgo&hot_deal=true")
#
dealblock = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("span")
for deal in dealblock:
    header = deal.find_element_by_class_name("percent-hot-deal__block")
    print(header.text)
#
time.sleep(15)

driver.quit()
```

Please help, if I need to edit anything, be sure to comment.
Also, I know that importin so many things is useless, I was following other tutorials on the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want to wait for the page to load and grab the element.

You can do something like this.

```
driver.get("https://shadowpay.com/en?price_from=0.00&price_to=34.00&game=csgo&hot_deal=true")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
dealblock = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span.percent-hot-deal__block")
#print(len(dealblock))
for deal in dealblock:
    print(deal.text)
```

The more ideal way is:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://shadowpay.com/en?price_from=0.00&price_to=34.00&game=csgo&hot_deal=true")
dealblock = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.percent-hot-deal__block")))
#print(len(dealblock))
for deal in dealblock:
    print(deal.text)
```

Imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import json
import requests 
r = requests.get('https://api.shadowpay.com/api/market/get_items?types=[]&exteriors=[]&rarities=[]&collections=[]&item_subcategories=[]&float={"from":0,"to":1}&price_from=0.00&price_to=34.00&game=csgo&hot_deal=true&stickers=[]&count_stickers=[]&short_name=&search=&stack=false&sort=desc&sort_column=price_rate&limit=50&offset=0')

for i in range(len(r.json()["items"])):
    try:
        print(r.json()["items"][i]["collection"]["name"], ",", r.json()["items"][i]["discount"])
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
```

Comment: But question, what would you type to get the skin name?